# Spark `FileAlreadyExistsException` when `saveAsTextFile` even though the output directory doesn't exist

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am running this command line:

```
hadoop fs -rm -r /tmp/output
```

And then a Java8 spark job with this `main()`

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    JavaRDD<JSONObject> rdd = sc.textFile("/tmp/input")
            .map (s -> new JSONObject(s))
    rdd.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/output");
    sc.stop();
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory /tmp/output already exists
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: I have used the following command in the SparkConf and it works perfectly well `yourSparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "false")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You remove HDFS directory but Spark try to save in local file system.

To save in hdfs try this:

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://<URL-hdfs>:<PORT-hdfs>/tmp/output");
```

defaults for localhost is:

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/output");
```

Other solution is remove `/tmp/output` from your local file system

Best regards